# redirect IP address to specific folder in IIS

Tags: iis-7, ip, website

So we have a server with server 2008 R2 and IIS7. IT pointed an external IP at the box and said, "there you go, you'll need to figure it out from here". It totally worked, but we have multiple sites setup, some internal and some external.

So My question is. How do I tell IIS that a specific site is for that specific IP?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a site in the IIS 7 manager, there will be an "Edit Bindings" link in the right-hand sidebar.  This will bring up a menu to edit the bindings; this is where you can modify the site's listeners to attach to a specific IP address.

Also worth considering would be to utilize host headers, so that you won't need to manage the bindings by IP (and use up a new external IP for every site).